# Where can I install the Development Package for Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am currently learning Kotlin Language for Android development and I am trying to install the development package for it, just like Java SE. Where can I find it? Some tutorial tells me to use IntellJIDEA to use the plug-in feature and directly start programming but I am trying to do that on NetBeans after installing the package. Where to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go with IntellJIDEA, because if you started to develop Android application on that time you will use Android Studio, both Android studio and IntellJIDEA IDE functionalities are same.

Comment: Yeah, I am already using Android Studio for development using Java, but it can only create an Android Project instead of a Kotlin one. Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: @YangXu, you need to manually install [kotlin plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin), it is not bundled by default.